# Low random read IOPS intel dc s4500

Tags: hp-proliant, ssd, intel, iops

i have very bad read performance on my new intel ssd. 
My configuration is:
HP proliant DL360e gen8 with Smart Array P222 controler.
Intel ssd dc s4500 960GB
64GB ram
2x Intel cpu

I have 2x SAS HDD 7200rpm(raid 0), 1x consumer Samsung SSD (raid 0) and 1x Intel s4500 (raid 0).

Operating system is intalled on SAS drives (Windows server 2016).

So my results are:

[image]

random read performance is low. Should be around 70 000 iops. Now 7253 iops. So cca 10x slower.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a filesystem on this drive?  If so, then you're likely to get benchmark results that are lower than the officially-published numbers.  Your benchmark tool will be doing I/O that goes through the OSes filesystem layer, which can be a bottleneck.  It's better if you leave the disk raw/uninitialized and use a tool like [iometer](http://www.iometer.org/) that can do raw disk I/O.  Also make sure that your SmartArray controller is configured to disable caching for that volume so that it's not servicing reads from cache and skewing your numbers.